# Basic CRUD application using spring and Hibernate 

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I have to develop a base implementation using spring MVC and hibernate that will show "search", "edit", "Add" "OK" and "Cancel" button in every pages, and each page will represent a table or more than one table (if parent-child relation is there). In case of search - it will display all record one-by-one with pagination based on filled ciriteria. (here all field will disable). In case of user clicks on edit - some editable field will enable and after pressing OK button it should update that record, otherwise in case of CANCEL button pressed it will again should be in search result. ADD will used to add new record with help of OK and Cancel button.

For this i want to use MultiActionController of Spring but how to use OK and Cancel button functionality, i don't have clue. Please help me.

Also i delevelop one DAO implementation class that will handle all table request for find, update, save using HibernateTemplete.

Comment: "spring and hibernate" is a rather bad question title.

Answer (score 1):

> I have seen such Example for CRUD operations in Spring MVC. but there
>   is a single table usage in it. It was really helpful to me, easy to
>   understand.
>   Here is a link http://sindhitutorials.com/blog/spring-mvc-hibernate-eclipse-maven/

Answer (score 0):

Check out [AppFuse](http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbMay2008.html) to get your edit stuff done quickly. This would help you get up and running quickly with Spring and Hibernate.